# Deserialize XML List<MyType>

Tags: c#, xml

Right now I have a XML file which looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMyMedia xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyMedia>
    <fileName>C:\Users\Yanis\Pictures\Photos\VID_20130704_203538.mp4</fileName>
    <title>VID_20130704_203538.mp4</title>
    <length>0</length>
    <_type>0</_type>
  </MyMedia>
  <MyMedia>
    <fileName>C:\Users\Yanis\Pictures\Photos\VID_20130802_142038.mp4</fileName>
    <title>VID_20130802_142038.mp4</title>
    <length>0</length>
    <_type>0</_type>
  </MyMedia>
</ArrayOfMyMedia>
```

This XML is generated by this function :

```
public void WriteXML(List<MyMedia> myMedias)
{

            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyMedia>));
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                @"c:\temp\SerializationOverview.xml");
            writer.Serialize(file, myMedias);
            file.Close();
}
```

And when I want to retrieve my list of medias of type : `List<MyMedias>`

With this function :

```
 public void LoadXML()
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyMedia>));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\temp\SerializationOverview.xml");
        window1.medias = (List<MyMedia>)reader.Deserialize(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < window1.medias.Count; i++)
        {
            window1.mediaList.Items.Add(window1.medias[i]);
        }
    }
```

Here is my "MyMedia" class, it's pretty simple though :

```
public class MyMedia
    {
        enum type
        {
            MUSIC,
            VIDEO,
            IMAGE
        };

        public String fileName { get; set; }
        public String artist { get; set; }
        public String title { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int _type { get; set; }

        public MyMedia()
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return title;
        }
    }
```

My window1.medias variable is empty.
Any clue ?

**Edit :** I found the solution, I had a field in my "MyMedia" class that was not in my .xml file. I removed it and it worked.

Comment: Yes, the count is zero

Comment: Can you post your class definition?

Comment: Your class contains a property "artist" but your XML file does not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I removed the "artist" field from my MyMedia class, but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: Is the tick mark at the end of the xml supposed to be there? That's just an accidental right?

Comment: Yep, just an aciddent (edited)

Comment: When I run your deserialize code it works for me. I took the tick mark off the end of the xml though. I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, the tick was NOT an error.
I took it off, and it worked.
I think this + the artist field that was remaining blank was the issue.
Now it works like a charm !

Thanks to all of you guys :)